# Transfer data to a server from a Symbian device with PhoneGap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, symbian

Because **PhoneGap/FileTransfer** not work on symbian,
  What choice do I have to send and receive information with a server?

Answer (score 0):

Just use normal HTTP protocol to send POST request to server.

Comment: The server only returns the response XML. 
How do I control the server's response with PhoneGap API?

Comment: Don't know about PhoneGap, but as you said - it doesn't work on Symbian, so parse the XML yourself.